# How to update record value in SML?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I am writing SML program to update records in a list.For example, I have type person_name.

```
type person_name = {fname:string, lname:string, mname:string}
```

Then I have person_bio which has person_name embedded in it.

```
type person_bio = {age:real, gender:string, name:person_name, status:string}
```

Next I have employee which has person_bio.

```
type employee = {p:person_bio, payrate:real, whours:real} list;
```

Now, I have to define function 'updateLastName' by passing the first name.

As of now, created one record 'e1' with below data.

```
{p={age=40.0,gender="M",name{fname="rob",lname="sen",mname=""},status="M"},
  payrate=30.0,whours=10.0}
```

But I am facing challenge to traverse the list and then updating one field in record.

```
fun updateLastName(x:string,l:employee)=
  if (L=[]) then []
  else if (x= #fname(#name(#p hd l))  //cheking name of 1st record in list

  //not getting how to update,this kind of line did not work
  #fname(#name(#p hd l) = "abc"

  else updateLastName(x,tl(l));    // hope this is right
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Values in SML are immutable, and `#fname(#name(#p hd l) = "abc"` is a comparison. You need to build a new list with the updated record. (And read up on pattern matching – it makes everything less messy and more readable.)

Comment: Start with something simpler than records, such as integers.

Comment: thanks,I am bit confused. To update lname only, i have to remove and add it someway if direct updation is not possible?

Comment: I did this to update lastname but not working.  fun updateLname(fnm:string,lnm:string,[]) = []   
|    updateLname(fnm:string,lnm:string,x::xs)=

 ( if fnm= (#fname ( #name ( #p x))) then
     if lnm <> (#lname ( #name ( #p ( x)))) then lnm else (#lname ( #name ( #p ( x))))) :: updateLname(fnm,lnm,xs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have stumbled upon something difficult: Updating a deeply nested record.

For records you have *getters*, so `#fname (#name (#p employee))` gets the field that you're checking against to know that this is the employee whose last name you are going to update. But records don't grant you equivalent *setters*, so you have to make those. If you're curious, [*lenses*](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/basic-lensing) (Haskell) are a general way to solve this, but I don't know of any implementation of lenses for Standard ML.

I'll go ahead and remove the `list` part in your `employee` type; you should probably want an `employee list` if you want multiple employees modelled, rather than to say that an employee is multiple persons.

```
type person_name = { fname:string, lname:string, mname:string }
type person_bio = { age:real, gender:string, name:person_name, status:string }
type employee = { p:person_bio, payrate:real, whours:real }

val name1 = { fname = "John", lname = "Doe", mname = "W." } : person_name
val bio1 = { age = 42.0, gender = "M", name = name1, status = "?" } : person_bio
val my_employee1 = { p = bio1, payrate = 1000.0, whours = 37.0 } : employee

val name2 = { fname = "Freddy", lname = "Mercury", mname = "X." } : person_name
val bio2 = { age = 45.0, gender = "M", name = name2, status = "?" } : person_bio
val my_employee2 = { p = bio2, payrate = 2000.0, whours = 37.0 } : employee

val my_employees = [ my_employee1, my_employee2 ] : employee list
```

As for the *setters* (the ones that you could automatically derive using *lenses*),

```
fun setP (p : person_bio, e : employee) =
    { p = p
    , payrate = #payrate e
    , whours = #whours e } : employee

fun setName (name : person_name, pb : person_bio) =
    { age = #age pb
    , gender = #gender pb
    , name = name
    , status = #status pb } : person_bio

fun setLname (lname, pn : person_name) =
    { fname = #fname pn
    , lname = lname
    , mname = #mname pn } : person_name
```

you can compose these, e.g. like:

```
- setP (setName (setLname ("Johnson", #name (#p my_employee1)), #p my_employee1), my_employee1)
> val it =
    {p =
           {age = 42.0, gender = "M",
            name = {fname = "John", lname = "Johnson", mname = "W."},
            status = "?"}, payrate = 1000.0, whours = 37.0} :
      {p :
         {age : real, gender : string,
          name : {fname : string, lname : string, mname : string},
          status : string}, payrate : real, whours : real}
```

Or you can split that line a little apart to make it more readable:

```
fun updateLname (fname, lname, employees) =
    let fun update employee =
            if #fname (#name (#p employee)) = fname
            then let val new_name = setLname (lname, #name (#p employee))
                     val new_bio = setName (new_name, #p employee)
                     val new_employee = setP (new_bio, employee)
                 in new_employee end
            else employee
    in List.map update employees
    end
```

Trying this out:

```
- updateLname ("Freddy", "Johnson", my_employees);
> val it =
    [{p = ... {fname = "John", lname = "Doe", mname = "W."}, ... },
     {p = ... {fname = "Freddy", lname = "Johnson", mname = "X."}, ... }]

- updateLname ("John", "Johnson", my_employees);
> val it =
    [{p = ... {fname = "John", lname = "Johnson", mname = "W."}, ... },
     {p = ... {fname = "Freddy", lname = "Mercury", mname = "X."}, ... }]
```

Comment: That idea of lenses seems interesting. I wonder how possible it would be to implement it in straight SML. I don't see why not, but on the other hand, I don't know what that link means when it refers to "Template Haskell".

Comment: You could generate lenses as part of a preprocessing step. If I were to make such a preprocessor, I'd probably extend the work of Morten Brøns-Pedersen's [PreML](https://github.com/br0ns/PreML) SML preprocessor.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaborate explanation.It helped a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your situation, references may be appropriate here.

For any values you may need to change, you can make them a reference, i.e.

```
type person_name = {fname:string, lname:string ref, mname:string}
type person_bio = {age:real, gender:string, name:person_name, status:string}
fun change_lname(new_lname: string, bio: person_bio) = (#lname (#name bio)) := new_lname

val p1 = ...
print !(#lname (#name p1)) ==> LastName1

change_lname("LastName2", p1)
print !(#lname (#name p1)) ==> LastName2
```

If you plan on modifying data in a record a lot, it's probably a good idea to make it a reference so that your program is not rewriting memory every time it needs to change one value (though in many situations the compiler/interpreter will be able to optimize this). It also saves you from having to rewrite setter functions if the signature of your record changes. The downside is that you'll be introducing complexity into your program by using references.

For example, in the above code, we're not actually modifying p1's last name, instead p1 and a copy (passed to the function) both point to the same string, and we modify that string in the function. At no point are we actually changing any of the data in either record, we're only changing data that the records point to. It's a subtle difference, and it doesn't really make a difference in this example, but it can lead to strange bugs that are hard to debug.